# Varnish : Cluster - Purge cache on all varnish hosts

Tags: http, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I am using the (free) version of varnsih (version 6).

Here is my configuration :

- 2 varnish hosts (varnish_A, varnish_B)
- 2 webs servers (node_A, node_B)

I only cache all the pages /app/api/client (GET) from my web servers and it's working very well

But I have a problem, when there is an update on the page (from a PUT) /app/api/client/test_data I added a BAN in the sub vcl_recv  part

```
if (req.url ~ "^app/api/client($|/.*)" &&  ( req.method == "POST" || req.method == "PUT" ))  {
ban("req.http.host == " + req.http.host + " && req.url == " + req.url);
std.syslog(180, "[debug]["+req.method+"] - Starting Purge of the cache for: " + req.http.host + req.url );
return (pass);
set req.backend_hint = web_node.backend();
}
```

The ban is working, but only on the current varnish host (for example varnish_B), so the other one (varnish_A) still has the old version of the object...

Does any one know how to "share" the ban on all host ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

### Send a ban to both Varnish servers

It's just a matter of running the ban on both Varnish servers, rather than on one. You can probably build that into your content management flow where the 2 endpoints are called.

### Varnish Broadcaster

Alternatively you could sign up for [Varnish Enterprise](https://www.varnish-software.com/solutions/varnish-enterprise/) and use the Varnish Broadcaster as your banning endpoint. It will distribute the request to all or to specific Varnish nodes. See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-broadcaster/examples/ for examples.

### Optimizing your bans

Just a sidenote, using `req.url` and `req.http.host` is not ideal for bans. When the ban is executed, the ban lurker doesn't have access to these variables, which means the banning is the responsibility of the next request.

A way to circumvent this limitation is by adding the following VCL code:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = bereq.http.host;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;
}
```

You could then run the following ban:

```
ban("obj.http.x-host ~ " + req.http.host + " && obj.http.x-url == " + req.url);
```

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/ban/ for a full tutorial on Varnish bans.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Just one question, what do you mean by   "You can probably build that into your content management flow where the 2 endpoints are called" ?

I will have a look on the tutorial

Comment: When content changes in your content management system, some hook will probably be used to call your ban endpoint. This will invalidate the right objects in the cache for that updated content. If that is the case, you could call both ban endpoints from that hook in your code.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. My varnish are behind a load balancer, my app server access to my varnish cluster with a virtual IP. So i guess it's not possible, directly in the vcl to ask the ban to be done in all host of the cluster, i am quit sad !

Comment: It is technically possible by registering the other Varnish server as an extra backend, call the `ban()` function and then set the backend to the secondary Varnish server and via `return(pass)` send the request to the other Varnish servers as well. This also requires checking the client IP for the incoming request to avoid loops.